# how to keep adding a number to a variable in the database in ejs

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, ejs, calculation

I have a variable `quantity` and another variable `new quantity`. whenever a user inputs the `new quantity` it should be added to previous sum of quantity.

i have a create form and an edit form. `quantity` field is on the create form while `newlyAdded` field is on the edit form

This is the schema snippet

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'), 
  stocksSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  number: Number,
  quantity: Number,
  newlyAdded: Number,
  sold: Number,
  newlySold: Number,
  balance: Number,
  description: String,
...
```

```html
ejs snippet
<% let justAdded = item.quantity + item.newlyAdded %>
        <td><%= justAdded %></a></td>
```

for example, if the `quantity = 10` and a user inputs `12` new figure should be `22` and if `10` is added again, new quantity should be `32` but instead it shows `22` because it doesnt store the previous additions. How the i fix this? I know the edit form isnt right for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out that mongodb which i'm using for the database has an increment operator `$inc` which solved the issue. see full [description](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc)

Answer (score 0):

generally, you have two way.

1. when user input the value, just update the value to newlyAdded field in mongo db & refresh. if you dont refresh, the value not changed newlyAdded because request to serer already finished.

2.update value to server is same. but, not redirect, you can controll dom directly.
use jquery or javascript.

it is the exampld use jquery.

```
<input id="input" type="text" .. />
 <td><a id="val"><%= justAdded %></a></td>
...
<script>

var oldVal = Number('<%= item.quantity %>');

$("#input").on("propertychange change keyup paste input", function() {
    var currentVal = Number($(this).val());
    var newVal = oldVal + currentVal;
    if(currentVal == newVal) {
        return;
    }
    $("#val").text(newVal);
    oldVal = newVal;    
});

</script>
```

Comment: This might have worked, but I did not want to mix things up. Like adding jquery